# 70cm perfect focus depth of field for product photography

Tags: depth-of-field, product-photography

Please look at this photo below, on the left is the full product, and on the right is the 100% crop of the same photo.

[image]

The guitar is around 100cm tall. If you incline by around 45°, you have about 70cm of depth of field.

As you can see, the photo has perfect focus from top to bottom.

My setup for product photography (with strobes) is usually 1/160, f/9 to 11, ISO 100, on Nikon D850 with a 24-70mm lens, and I could never be able to obtain that sharpness and that depth of field.

What do you think is the setup for this very long and sharp depth of field?

I don't think that it is a case of focus stacking because of expensive post-production. They have "millions" of products, I don't think they do focus stacking for productivity reasons.

Do you think that it could be a 150-200mm zoom lens and shoot from a certain distance?

I thought about wide-angle lenses (10-15mm)m but the product looks too "flat" for a wide angle (unless they apply lens corrections), but I could be wrong.

The photo is taken from here:
https://www.thomann.de/it/fender_cp_60s_parlor_natural_wn.htm (product page)
https://bdbo1.thomann.de/thumb/bdb3000/pics/bdbo/13890291.jpg (direct link to photo)

Comment: Note that using a longer focus length will lead to an even smaller DOF than you had before unless you move away significantly. The answers given basically are the only two viable solutions if you want no distortions, full sharpness and best image quality.

Comment: It could simply be shot with a phone or other tiny sensor camera, maybe an optical zoom pocket P+S. One big reason I got a 300D back in the horse-and-buggy days was because my S330 digital elph had virtually no bokeh/separation. You could also go pinhole (~infinite DoF) if you have non-battery strobes and don't need huge enlargements...

Answer (score 27, accepted):

For me this is perfect fit for tilt lens. Moving the focus plane to be parallel to the guitar you will be able to get focus of entire guitar (in displayed position). Even if you use relatively open aperture.

As idea Nikon PC-E Micro-NIKKOR 45mm f/2.8D ED Tilt-Shift lens can help you.

Comment: in fact, Nikon uses similar guitar image to advertise that lens https://www.nikonusa.com/en/nikon-products/product/camera-lenses/pc-e-micro-nikkor-45mm-f%252f2.8d-ed.html

Answer (score 11):

And the other option besides the one Romeo Ninov mentions (tilt lens) is focus stacking.

Basically is adjusting focus bit by bit taking several shots. This is better done manually doing the focus.

If you can do it tethering the camera and adjusting the focus point remotely.

You need a lens that has limited focus breathing.

Look for software that can merge the different shots like Helicon Focus.

You mention that it is probably not likely to be used, but those programs have batch mode, so they can be used on a large scale. Stacking 5 photos will take less time than the one spent framing and aligning the pice, so if you have a good workflow and a team of people, it can be done in almost "real time".

Comment: I believe at least one of the Nikon bodies will do an automatic focus stack of up to 30 frames.

Comment: As will some of the Olympus bodies.

Comment: My Canon will do it too, or at least help automate taking the pictures and do it in their software later.

Answer (score 1):

Using a long focal length and a small aperture is a third option besides tilting the lens and focus stacking.

This means setting the camera further away.

A camera with a small sensor will also provide more depth of field at any given aperture due to using a shorter focal length for a given field of view relative to a larger sensor camera.

And depending on application, you may not need a very large sensor or a very high resolution. The question is what does the client actually need and what are they paying for?

But a tilt lens is what I would use.